# Sort or Filter Members in Control Panel

Tags: members, filter

I'm hoping to provide a client with the ability to filter custom member fields in the CP.

I know [Zenbu](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu) has this functionality for channels, but I need it specifically for members and their [custom] fields. Does anyone know if anything like this exists? I can build something front-end, but would like to keep it isolated to the CP.

Edit: I realize this is probably best accomplished with something like [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor). Just wondering if there is anything else out there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any addons that does this.

But there is no reason you can't build this yourself in a custom template which only the SuperAdmin members can see... then link to the template from inside the CP.

The [**jQuery Tablesorter plugin**](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) would handle the sorting for you and a custom query to get the member data that you need.